# Get column values from MongoDB table to Django

Tags: python, django, mongodb, http

How should I create a `model.py`, when I already have an existing `mongoDB` database.

I only want to get the values from an existing `Table` to a the `HttpResponse` in `Django views.py`.

Is there any reference material for me to go over this?

Comment: Correct formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Django internally doesn't support mongo directly and you should handle your tasks manually. (fetch data and render it yourself)

I recommend checking [mongoengine](http://mongoengine.org/) which provides a django-orm like api for mongo which can be nice.

If you don't like mongoengine you can always use `pymongo`, the official python module for mongo